# How to use a variable of a function in another function of same class -Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to assign the value of `$Id` from `firstFunction` to the variable `$temp` in `secondFunction`.

```
public function firstFunction()
{
    $Id = $_POST['quizID_click'];
}


public function secondFunction()
{
    $temp = ------;
}
```

Please let me know how to access `$Id` in `secondFunction`

Comment: create it as a property of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to pass only a variable inside the Controller functions, You can do it by throwing a flash like this:

```
    public function firstFunction()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $Id = $_POST['quizID_click'];
        $this->session->set_flashdata('item', $Id);
    }


    public function secondFunction()
    {
        $myVar = $this->session->flashdata('item');
    }
```

Basically you temporary save the variable value as flashdata giving it a `'item'` value `'item'` can be anything. then the second controller looks for this flashdata and asigns it to `$myVar`

Comment: Why are you using sessions for this? He could simply call the 2nd function from the first with a param, like you'd always do? What is the benefit of doing it through a session?

Comment: @killstreet the second method might be a big and doesn't return only one variable, u cannot access a variable unless u return it with a function, but a function can not always be used to return one variable

Comment: In cases you need to return multiple variables you would just create an array

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment, you could create your variable as a property of your class.. it's been a while since used CI so forgive me, classes are classes though :)

```
class whatever
{
    public $id;

    public function firstFunction($postData)
    {
         $this->id = $postData['quizID_click'];
    }

    public function secondFunction()
    {
        $temp = $this->id;
    }
}
```

Hope that gets you going

Answer (score 1):

Functions create **local** variables which are destroyed when the function completed. To maintain the variable you need, you'll have to return it from the function and then assign it to a variable.

I can see that you are using classes, so you'll need to access the function like a method. This should work:

```
public function firstFunction()
{
    $Id = $_POST['quizID_click'];
    return $Id;
}


public function secondFunction()
{
    $temp = $this->firstFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a public variables of your class so that you can access the variables in all methods.

```
class myClass{
    public $id;

    public function first(){
        $this->id = $this->input->post('quizID_click');
    }

    public function second(){
        $id = $this->id;
    }
}
```

But that depends on what you are tying to accomplish? Please elaborate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function firstFunction()
{
    $Id = $_POST['quizID_click'];
    $this->seconFunction($id);
}


 public function secondFunction($id)
 {
     $temp = $id;
 }
```

This is how to pass variables among functions.