# call variabel from other function (php)

Tags: php, function, variables

I have this code

```
class foo
{
    function one()
    {
        $number = 1;
    }

    function two()
    {
        echo $number;
    }

}
```

And i want to call $number from `function one()` on `function two()`.
Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Yes. This is so simple, you have to research further. You can do it. I know you can.

Comment: yeah, i can do it if i echo the $number on first function and call on second function. but i can't echo $number from first function to second function

Comment: You have to learn the very foundation and fundamentals of classes and functions in php. We will not spoon feed you with this simple question. Do research more.

Comment: Good on you, @AlivetoDie.  Here is the link I was going to close with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33689136/2943403

Comment: ok, thank you very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello Mfdsix Indo,**

Try this code,

```
class foo
{
    function one()
    {
        $number = 1;
        return $number;
    }

    function two()
    {
        echo $this->one();
    }
}
```

OR

```
class foo
{
    private $number;
    function one()
    {
        $this->number = 1;
    }

    function two()
    {
        echo $this->number;
    }
}
```

I hope my answer id helpful.
If any query so comment please.

Comment: yeah, it works. but how can i do that without return the number variable first ?

Comment: Now updated my answer...

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. it's mean that i must run one and two function. But no matter, it's ok for me.

Comment: Yes because one() function set the value and two() function set the print the value.

Comment: You can also set as static variable number.

Comment: done............................